# JavaScript DOM traversal order

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following page to demonstrate DOM traversing:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DOM Traversal</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>
<p>Sample paragraph</p>
</div>
<h1>Sample H1</h1>

<script>

// Traversing the DOM tree
"use strict";
var node = document.body;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    while(node) {
        console.log(node);
        node = node.firstChild;
    }
}, false);

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

According to me, the output should be body -> div -> p but it is body -> #text. Can somebody explain what is #text and why I'm not getting the desired order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are "empty-text" nodes, I blogged about them here:

https://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/secret-covert-hush-hush-white-space-in-the-dom-exposed

They are explained here: http://www.w3.org/DOM/faq.html#emptytext

Comment: Thanks a lot for the blog post! Awesome discussion and what an eye-opener!

Comment: In your blog you mention `prevElementSibling`.  Should be `previousElementSibling`.

Answer (score 1):

There's whitespace between `body` and `div`:

```
<body>

<div>
```

That whitespace, though conceptually empty, exists and is part of the DOM.  It's interpreted as `#text` in this traversal.  (You'll probably see *a lot* of `#text` nodes.)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try to access [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.firstElementChild), which ignores nodes which do not have a [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.nodeType) equal to 1, such as text elements.

---